# SASS plugin for CSS3 cross-browser compatibility?

Tags: ruby, css, cross-browser, sass, vendor-neutrality

Is there a SASS extension that would take SASS stylesheets, find neutral properties (e.g. `border-radius`) and output all vendor-specific properties for it (e.g. `-webkit-border-radius` etc) automatically?

I don't really want to create all the mixins manually nor write the code manually. I'm sure there must be such an extension, but I can't find it. Help?

Comment: Grunt will also do the job. With its autoprefixer. This way you run the code directly on generated css and not on actuall sass file.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-autoprefixe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very nice gem that would fit your needs. It's called [Bourbon](https://github.com/thoughtbot/bourbon)

It will not replace your css with the vendor-specific one as it works as SASS is made to work.

It is basically a mixin collection that generates the cross-browser css properly.

Answer (score 1):

[Compass](http://compass-style.org) has a [CSS3 module](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/) that handles a lot of that stuff.

Comment: Yes, but Compass requires me to `@include border-radius`. What I was thinking about was writing normal, non-mixin code and have it compiled/converted to the respective vendors.